# Does Surinder Singh route apply to Extended family members?

Tags: european-union

Surinder Singh route applies to Core family members of EU citizens (and I believe this includes dependent parents too?).

But does the Surinder Singh route apply to Extended family members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, subject to one additional condition that does not apply to immediate family members.

The core element of the Surinder Singh route is to establish whether a British citizen must be treated as an EEA national for the purpose of free movement law in the United Kingdom.  Once that is established, all of the free movement provisions apply, both for family members and extended family members of the British citizen.

This arises from regulation 9 of the [Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016, as amended](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052), which gives effect to the Surinder Singh ruling:

> Family members and extended family members of British citizens
>
> 9.—(1) If the conditions in paragraph (2) are satisfied, these Regulations apply to a person who is the family member (“F”) of a British citizen (“BC”) as though the BC were an EEA national.
>
> (1A) These Regulations apply to a person who is the extended family member (“EFM”) of a BC as though the BC were an EEA national if—
>
> (a) the conditions in paragraph (2) are satisfied; and
> (b) the EFM was lawfully resident in the EEA State referred to in paragraph (2)(a)(i).

Comment: (1) Are you 100% sure? (2) This is true for **all EU countries** and not **just** the UK right?

Comment: @JayShah I just read your other question about extended family members, so I would note that successfully invoking the Surinder Singh route does not change the fact that extended family members have far weaker rights than immediate family members.  As to other countries, the principle should be applicable to all of them, but the name "Surinder Singh" is likely to be found only in the UK, since that case concerned the UK.

Comment: @JayShah I just added a quotation from the relevant regulation.  If you're interested in some country other than the UK, you might want to edit the question or ask a new one.  You might also consider [Expatriates.SE], which has a good deal of material on this, and [Travel.SE], where Surinder Singh also comes up (occasionally) because it can be relevant to short-term trips as well as to immigration.

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer that one too please?

Comment: I understand that EFMs have weaker rights, but let's suppose that the scenario happens in reality.

Comment: @JayShah I can't answer the other question because I don't understand it fully, and because it would in practice depend on the country in question. It's very difficult to talk so generally because the person making the generalization might over- or under-generalize, as might the person answering the question. If you have a specific set of circumstances in mind, you will get more useful answers if you state these circumstances in your questions. *Yes,* Surinder Singh applies to extended family members in general, but it might not apply to *you,* or the family members might not qualify as EFMs.

Comment: I understand. That's fine.

Comment: I have narrowed the question. See if you could answer it now. @phoog Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

EU citizens have the right to free movement Including bringing nonEU family members to any *other* EU country, but not their own. Some countries don’t allow free movement to that country itself at all. Some just allow it. And some allow the “Surinder Singh” Route which allows free movement from another EU country to their own.

If general EU rules don’t apply to a more distant family member, then Surinder Singh is unlikely to apply, but it depends on the rules of your own country. It also only applies when you are moving yourself.

Comment: "some allow the 'Surinder Singh' route': as far as I am aware, they all have to allow it, because the court declared that failing to do so was an impermissible burden on free movement.